# Create UNION with one or more views in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, view, union, union-all

I am trying to get the union of a query and a view or a view and a view. But doing this in MySql gives back an `ER_PARSE_ERROR`.

So say I have a view called `B_SAL` for the state of a particular data set before a particular operation.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW B_SAL AS 
       SELECT * FROM EMP ORDER BY EMP.COMM;
```

After that operation I want to get the `UNION ALL` of `B_SAL` and the current state of the data set, in this case `EMP`.

```
       (SELECT * FROM EMP ORDER BY EMP.COMM)
       UNION ALL
       B_SAL
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  A `union all` doesn't sounds like something useful.

Comment: You do have to select from the view you can't just throw the view name in after the union.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Desired result depends heavily on the operation in between those two querys and another operation plus some sample data would make this question a bit too long and the question would lose focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to select from that view, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM EMP
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B_SAL;
```

But the above union is not good practice, because we are doing `SELECT *`, rather than explicitly listing out the columns we want to use.  A better version would look something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM EMP
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM B_SAL;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was too obvious!